# CS1069 C# System.Data.Odbc

Tags: c#, unity3d, odbc

Возникла проблема с System.Data.Odbc. Делаю в проекте на unity 2019.4.20f1(.NET Standard 2.0)

> Не удалось найти имя типа "OdbcCommand" в пространстве имен "System.Data.Odbc". Этот тип был отправлен в сборку "System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Попробуйте добавить ссылку на эту сборку.

Устанавливал System.Data 4 версии - не помогло. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Версия .NET какая?

Comment: А в Unity используется .NET?  Так 5.0.401.

Comment: Конечно используется, и точно не 5 версии. У вас разве где-то указано, что это Unity? Укажите версию Unity, кому надо - тот в курсе, какой у нее .NET.